# Chrome Push Notifications with XHR(using JavaScript without PHP)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, push-notification

Please explain how to do push notifications with XHR and Javascript.

I have done push notifications with the help of XHR and PHP, but I want to know how to do **push notifications through an AJAX request with javascript only**.

I am always getting error code 401 or 400 with the following code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
  type: "POST",
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','key=API_KEY');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  },
  registration_ids: [
    "SUBSCRIPTION_ENDPOINTS"
  ],
  payload: {
    data:{
      "score":"50"
    }
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: i think gcm only work with server .client side push not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can show answer on your question in Google by request "AJAX cross domain request" or "CORS".